# Pass file name from file upload control to filestream

Tags: c#, upload, mp3

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DDPRO8-WIN7X86\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mp3bytes;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated security=true; User ID=; Password=;");
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlParameter param = null;
    cmd = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO mp3_bytes (songs) " + " Values (@songs) ", conn);
    FileStream fs = null;

    string path = fileUpload.FileName;
    fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    Byte[] song = new Byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(song, 0, song.Length);
    fs.Close();
    param = new SqlParameter("@songs", SqlDbType.VarBinary, song.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, song);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

where fileUpload is the file upload control. I am uploading an mp3 file.
When I execute this I'm getting could not find file '', how can I pass the uploaded filename to filestream from upload file control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName`

Also its better to check if there is any file that has been uploaded using `fileUpload.HasFile` property. You can also guard against zero length files by checking against `fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0`.

**Edit: just realized your mistake**

The uploaded file content needs to saved by you on the disk using `fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs` method. The above file name property will give you file name on the client machine, but the file will not exist on the server. You need to save it wherever you want on server. For example,

```
var path = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, fileUpload.PostedFile.FileNam);
fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
```

This would put the uploaded file in the temp directory on the server. You can also use `PostedFile.InputStream` to read file contents.

`fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` will never work as file does not exist on web server machine.

**Edit: based on your sample code**

Remove `FileStream fs = null;` and replace

```
fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

with

```
var fs = uploadFile.PostedFile.InputStream;
```

and that should do the trick.

Comment: Happy for you that it works, but you really shouldn't be storing such large binary objects in a database.  How about storing them on disk and then just storing the file name / location in the db?

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need to use a FileStream, then you'll need to set the FileMode to Create rather than Open as you're not Opening a file, you're Creating one.

```
fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
```

EDIT: But, as VinayC says, SaveAs() does all the hard work for you!

EDIT: It looks like you are trying to save the file to disk, then read the bytes from the file to pass to sql.  You can bypass that saving / reading part by just getting `FileBytes` from the `FileUpload` control.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DDPRO8-WIN7X86\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mp3bytes;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated security=true; User ID=; Password=;");
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlParameter param = null;
cmd = new SqlCommand(" INSERT INTO mp3_bytes (songs) " + " Values (@songs) ", conn);

param = new SqlParameter("@songs", SqlDbType.VarBinary, fileUpload.FileBytes.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, fileUpload.FileBytes);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```